# Sum rows with no field to group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2012 and I'm trying to sum rows of a table. Problem is I don't have a column to group by. Is this possible...? How would you raise the query?

Original table:

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | User | Salary |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | John | 150    |
| 2  | Marie| 120    |
| 3  | Willy| 125    |
| 4  | Juan | 110    |
| 5  |Carlos| 145    |
| 6  | Mike | 115    |
| 7  | Elsie| 100    |
| 8  | Elvie| 500    |
+----+------+--------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID |  USER  | SALARY |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 1plus2 |    270 |
|  2 | 1plus3 |    275 |
|  3 | 1to4   |    205 |
|  4 | 1plus8 |    650 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the expected output? What happened to id's > 4? Where are those users coming from?

Comment: Why do you sum rows with ID 1 and 2, then 1 and 3, then 1 through 4, then 1 and 8? Where's the logic behind it?

Comment: Logic is missing to `group by`

Comment: That question doesn't make sense...

Comment: I'd expect 1to4 to be 405.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the groups using a table constructor.  For instance, for the first two:

```
select v.new_user, sum(salary)
from t join
     (values ('1plus2', 1), ('1plus2', 2),
             ('1plus3', 1), ('1plus3', 3)
     ) v(new_user, user)
     on t.user = v.user
group by v.new_user;
```

Just expand the `values()` clause to add more groups of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all possible permutations, you could use a self join, This would only give you all permutations for two different users. For the third user you would need anotehr self join and so on.

```
select CONCAT(t1.User,"plus", t2.User),  (t1.Salary + t2.Salary) 
FROM mytable as t1 join mytable as t2 
ON t1.ID <> t2.ID;
```